# Equivalent of tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.attention_decoder in tensorflow 2 after upgrade

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, seq2seq, tensorflow1.15

I have the following code in TensorFlow 1.0. I tried to migrate it to TensorFlow 2.0 using tf_upgrade_v2 script. However, it didnt find an equivalent function in the tf-2 compact version.

I was recommended to use tensorflow_addons. However, I dont see an equivalent attention_decoder in the tf_addons module. Please guide me.

```
decoder_outputs,decoder_state = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.attention_decoder(
            decoder_inputs = decoder_inputs,
            initial_state = encoder_state,
            attention_states = encoder_outputs,
            cell = cell,
            output_size = word_embedding_dim,
            loop_function = None if mode=='pretrain' else feed_prev_loop,
            scope = scope
        )
```

The link to tf 1.0 code is here:
https://github.com/yaushian/CycleGAN-sentiment-transfer/blob/master/lib/seq2seq.py

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Any leads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is no equivalent in Tensorflow 2.x API, the [original implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.5/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L537) can be revised to be compatible with the new API. I have made the conversion below, along with a simple test case to verify it runs successfully.

```
# https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.5/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L537
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import variable_scope
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import nn_ops
from tensorflow.python.util import nest
from tensorflow.python.ops import init_ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import constant_op

import tensorflow as tf


class Linear:
    """Linear map: sum_i(args[i] * W[i]), where W[i] is a variable.
  Args:
    args: a 2D Tensor or a list of 2D, batch, n, Tensors.
    output_size: int, second dimension of weight variable.
    dtype: data type for variables.
    build_bias: boolean, whether to build a bias variable.
    bias_initializer: starting value to initialize the bias
      (default is all zeros).
    kernel_initializer: starting value to initialize the weight.
  Raises:
    ValueError: if inputs_shape is wrong.
  """

    def __init__(self,
                 args,
                 output_size,
                 build_bias,
                 bias_initializer=None,
                 kernel_initializer=None):
        self._build_bias = build_bias

        if args is None or (nest.is_sequence(args) and not args):
            raise ValueError("`args` must be specified")
        if not nest.is_sequence(args):
            args = [args]
            self._is_sequence = False
        else:
            self._is_sequence = True

        # Calculate the total size of arguments on dimension 1.
        total_arg_size = 0
        shapes = [a.get_shape() for a in args]
        for shape in shapes:
            if shape.ndims != 2:
                raise ValueError("linear is expecting 2D arguments: %s" % shapes)
            if shape.dims[1].value is None:
                raise ValueError("linear expects shape[1] to be provided for shape %s, "
                                 "but saw %s" % (shape, shape[1]))
            else:
                total_arg_size += shape.dims[1].value

        dtype = [a.dtype for a in args][0]

        scope = variable_scope.get_variable_scope()
        with variable_scope.variable_scope(scope) as outer_scope:
            self._weights = variable_scope.get_variable(
                'weights', [total_arg_size, output_size],
                dtype=dtype,
                initializer=kernel_initializer)
            if build_bias:
                with variable_scope.variable_scope(outer_scope) as inner_scope:
                    inner_scope.set_partitioner(None)
                    if bias_initializer is None:
                        bias_initializer = init_ops.constant_initializer(0.0, dtype=dtype)
                    self._biases = variable_scope.get_variable(
                        'bias', [output_size],
                        dtype=dtype,
                        initializer=bias_initializer)

    def __call__(self, args):
        if not self._is_sequence:
            args = [args]

        if len(args) == 1:
            res = math_ops.matmul(args[0], self._weights)
        else:
            # Explicitly creating a one for a minor performance improvement.
            one = constant_op.constant(1, dtype=dtypes.int32)
            res = math_ops.matmul(array_ops.concat(args, one), self._weights)
        if self._build_bias:
            res = nn_ops.bias_add(res, self._biases)
        return res


def attention_decoder(decoder_inputs,
                      initial_state,
                      attention_states,
                      cell,
                      output_size=None,
                      num_heads=1,
                      loop_function=None,
                      dtype=None,
                      scope=None,
                      initial_state_attention=False):
    """RNN decoder with attention for the sequence-to-sequence model.
  In this context "attention" means that, during decoding, the RNN can look up
  information in the additional tensor attention_states, and it does this by
  focusing on a few entries from the tensor. This model has proven to yield
  especially good results in a number of sequence-to-sequence tasks. This
  implementation is based on http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7449 (see below for
  details). It is recommended for complex sequence-to-sequence tasks.
  Args:
    decoder_inputs: A list of 2D Tensors [batch_size x input_size].
    initial_state: 2D Tensor [batch_size x cell.state_size].
    attention_states: 3D Tensor [batch_size x attn_length x attn_size].
    cell: tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell defining the cell function and size.
    output_size: Size of the output vectors; if None, we use cell.output_size.
    num_heads: Number of attention heads that read from attention_states.
    loop_function: If not None, this function will be applied to i-th output in
      order to generate i+1-th input, and decoder_inputs will be ignored, except
      for the first element ("GO" symbol). This can be used for decoding,
      but also for training to emulate http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03099.
        Signature -- loop_function(prev, i) = next * prev is a 2D Tensor of
        shape [batch_size x output_size], * i is an integer, the step number
        (when advanced control is needed), * next is a 2D Tensor of shape
        [batch_size x input_size].
    dtype: The dtype to use for the RNN initial state (default: tf.float32).
    scope: VariableScope for the created subgraph; default: "attention_decoder".
    initial_state_attention: If False (default), initial attentions are zero. If
      True, initialize the attentions from the initial state and attention
      states -- useful when we wish to resume decoding from a previously stored
      decoder state and attention states.
  Returns:
    A tuple of the form (outputs, state), where:
      outputs: A list of the same length as decoder_inputs of 2D Tensors of
        shape [batch_size x output_size]. These represent the generated outputs.
        Output i is computed from input i (which is either the i-th element
        of decoder_inputs or loop_function(output {i-1}, i)) as follows.
        First, we run the cell on a combination of the input and previous
        attention masks:
          cell_output, new_state = cell(linear(input, prev_attn), prev_state).
        Then, we calculate new attention masks:
          new_attn = softmax(V^T * tanh(W * attention_states + U * new_state))
        and then we calculate the output:
          output = linear(cell_output, new_attn).
      state: The state of each decoder cell the final time-step.
        It is a 2D Tensor of shape [batch_size x cell.state_size].
  Raises:
    ValueError: when num_heads is not positive, there are no inputs, shapes
      of attention_states are not set, or input size cannot be inferred
      from the input.
  """
    if not decoder_inputs:
        raise ValueError("Must provide at least 1 input to attention decoder.")
    if num_heads < 1:
        raise ValueError("With less than 1 heads, use a non-attention decoder.")
    if attention_states.get_shape()[2] is None:
        raise ValueError("Shape[2] of attention_states must be known: %s" %
                         attention_states.get_shape())
    if output_size is None:
        output_size = cell.output_size

    with variable_scope.variable_scope(
            scope or "attention_decoder", dtype=dtype) as scope:
        dtype = scope.dtype

        batch_size = array_ops.shape(decoder_inputs[0])[0]  # Needed for reshaping.
        attn_length = attention_states.get_shape()[1]
        if attn_length is None:
            attn_length = array_ops.shape(attention_states)[1]
        attn_size = attention_states.get_shape()[2]

        # To calculate W1 * h_t we use a 1-by-1 convolution, need to reshape before.
        hidden = array_ops.reshape(attention_states,
                                   [-1, attn_length, 1, attn_size])
        hidden_features = []
        v = []
        attention_vec_size = attn_size  # Size of query vectors for attention.
        for a in range(num_heads):
            k = variable_scope.get_variable(
                "AttnW_%d" % a, [1, 1, attn_size, attention_vec_size], dtype=dtype)
            hidden_features.append(nn_ops.conv2d(hidden, k, [1, 1, 1, 1], "SAME"))
            v.append(
                variable_scope.get_variable(
                    "AttnV_%d" % a, [attention_vec_size], dtype=dtype))

        state = initial_state

        def attention(query):
            """Put attention masks on hidden using hidden_features and query."""
            ds = []  # Results of attention reads will be stored here.
            if nest.is_sequence(query):  # If the query is a tuple, flatten it.
                query_list = nest.flatten(query)
                for q in query_list:  # Check that ndims == 2 if specified.
                    ndims = q.get_shape().ndims
                    if ndims:
                        assert ndims == 2
                query = array_ops.concat(query_list, 1)
            for a in range(num_heads):
                with variable_scope.variable_scope("Attention_%d" % a):
                    y = Linear(query, attention_vec_size, True)(query)
                    y = array_ops.reshape(y, [-1, 1, 1, attention_vec_size])
                    y = math_ops.cast(y, dtype)
                    # Attention mask is a softmax of v^T * tanh(...).
                    s = math_ops.reduce_sum(v[a] * math_ops.tanh(hidden_features[a] + y),
                                            [2, 3])
                    a = nn_ops.softmax(math_ops.cast(s, dtype=dtypes.float32))
                    # Now calculate the attention-weighted vector d.
                    a = math_ops.cast(a, dtype)
                    d = math_ops.reduce_sum(
                        array_ops.reshape(a, [-1, attn_length, 1, 1]) * hidden, [1, 2])
                    ds.append(array_ops.reshape(d, [-1, attn_size]))
            return ds

        outputs = []
        prev = None
        batch_attn_size = array_ops.stack([batch_size, attn_size])
        attns = [
            array_ops.zeros(batch_attn_size, dtype=dtype) for _ in range(num_heads)
        ]
        for a in attns:  # Ensure the second shape of attention vectors is set.
            a.set_shape([None, attn_size])
        if initial_state_attention:
            attns = attention(initial_state)
        for i, inp in enumerate(decoder_inputs):
            if i > 0:
                variable_scope.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            # If loop_function is set, we use it instead of decoder_inputs.
            if loop_function is not None and prev is not None:
                with variable_scope.variable_scope("loop_function", reuse=True):
                    inp = loop_function(prev, i)
            # Merge input and previous attentions into one vector of the right size.
            input_size = inp.get_shape().with_rank(2)[1]
            if input_size is None:
                raise ValueError("Could not infer input size from input: %s" % inp.name)

            inputs = [inp] + attns
            inputs = [math_ops.cast(e, dtype) for e in inputs]
            x = Linear(inputs, input_size, True)(inputs)
            # Run the RNN.
            cell_output, state = cell(x, state)
            # Run the attention mechanism.
            if i == 0 and initial_state_attention:
                with variable_scope.variable_scope(
                        variable_scope.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True):
                    attns = attention(state)
            else:
                attns = attention(state)

            with variable_scope.variable_scope("AttnOutputProjection"):
                cell_output = math_ops.cast(cell_output, dtype)
                inputs = [cell_output] + attns
                output = Linear(inputs, output_size, True)(inputs)
            if loop_function is not None:
                prev = output
            outputs.append(output)

    return outputs, state


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _outputs, _state = attention_decoder([tf.ones((1, 1))],
                                         tf.ones((1, 1)),
                                         tf.ones((1, 1, 1)),
                                         tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(1))
    print(_outputs, _state)
```

As mentioned in the [Github Issue for the same question](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/2664):

```
There is no direct replacement for this function but there are modules that achieve the same thing.

You can extend your RNN cell with an attention mechanism using tfa.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper
You can create a decoder with the RNN cell using tfa.seq2seq.BasicDecoder
There are small examples in these pages which should get you started with these modules.
```

The optimal approach is probably using new RNN and Attention modules introduced in the 2.x API, but for the sake of experimenting with scripts which were written using the 1.x API, similar to the one referenced in the question, this approach may be enough to bridge the gap.